# SilverLight / WP7: Can i use .net open source frameworks with silverlight & WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Does anyone know if its possible to use standard frameworks etc in silverlight & WP7?

Or does it have to actually support silverlight specifically..??

Silverlight is a cut down verison of .net if i am not mistaken... so maybe all open source apis, frameworks etc may not work?

any ideas really appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're right, a library has to support Silverlight specifically.

If a library is open source, you could try to build it yourself against the Silverlight runtime. If it doesn't depend on too specific stuff, you might be lucky to get it work after a few tweaks.

Comment: An additional note is that while Silverlight is a "lighter" version of the .NET framework, the  Windows Phone 7 isn't a full implementation of Silverlight either so there are some features that are not available on WP7.